# Disk cleanup doesn't work on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, disk-cleanup

When I am trying to clean the 2.53 GB of old "Windows Updates" by pressing "OK" in

[image]

and then re-open the clean up window, all those old updates are still there.
I ran

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore
```

(here I get error 87 "The option analyzecomponentstore is not recognized in this context."

[image]

See the `dism.log` at https://pastebin.com/6gkw9iPx.

)

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```

following https://answers.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/forum/all/update-bereinigung-funktioniert-nicht/59e06edf-2079-4718-91d5-752e82284940, but that did not change anything. What might be the issue and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Please include in your post the entire error 87 message. Are you running DISM as Admin?

Comment: @harrymc: I added the information. Yes, admin.

Comment: Could you also post the file `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log`.

Comment: @harrymc: I uploaded the file to pastbin - see question.

Comment: How old are these past updates.  There are rules that even */Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup* will follow

Comment: Is Windows fully updated? AnalyzeComponentStore was a later addition, and it's not recognized on your computer.

Comment: @harrymc: Yes, it is fully updated.

Comment: @Ramhound: I am not sure. I updated today, but there was only one update (if I recall correctly). Before I updated, the disk cleanup manager already showed a substantial amount of space, which could be cleaned. How do I find find out, such that I may answer your question properly?

Comment: @Make42 - Windows Update History. AnalyzeComponentStore only exists on Windows 10, so the command will literally do nothing on Windows 8.1 as expected.  I strongly suspect that `/StartComponentCleanup` is also a Windows 10-only command.  There is a workaround but are you positive you want to reset the history of WIndows Updiate?  That will mean it will be impossible to rollback any previous updates

Comment: I suggest to update to Windows 10, if you can.

Comment: @Ramhound: I do not want to do anything that is ill advised. I just wanted to clean some space, but if it is a bad idea in this case, I will not do it.

Comment: Why don't you use disk cleanup in Explorer : right-click C, Properties, Disk Clean-up?

Comment: @harrymc: That is what I did. Then, secondly, I pressed on "Clean up system files" in the disk cleanup program. That opens the dialogue you see in the question.

Comment: Enabling all options in the dialog is the most you can do to clean up on Windows 8.1. Although AnalyzeComponentStore is said by some documentation to exist in Windows 8.1, your experience shows that it was only introduced later on in Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc: Well, I interpreted the 2.53 GB to be what _can_ be deleted not the amount of space that the updates is taking up.

Answer (score 0):

Windows locks some update files for a period of time. Some disk cleanup tools, such as [Wise Disk Cleaner](https://www.wisecleaner.com/landingpage/wisediskcleaner.html), or [some alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/wise-disk-cleaner/), seem to bypass that time-lock, allowing removal of downloaded update files. After an update, hundreds of megabytes of files can be safely removed. *N.B.* Windows *Restore Points* take up considerable disk space; **if you regularly make full disk images**, consider deleting all *Restore Points* and turn off *Restore Point* protection.

[image: Wise Disk Cleaner MS Update Cleanup]

That said, now would be a good time to consider an alternative to Windows 8.1, particularly if the machine using it has connection to the internet. [Windows 8.1 end-of-life is approaching in a few months](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-81), and there will be no further security updates. If you don't want to update to a later Windows version, consider testing an alternative OS, such as Linux. To see if a new OS is suitable, run it from a live USB, e.g., [Ubuntu's](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#3-boot-from-usb-flash-drive), **which makes no changes to the existing HDD/SSD** and requires no installation.

Comment: As I said to harrymc: I interpreted the 2.53 GB to be what _can_ be deleted not the amount of space that the updates is taking up. Thanks for the suggestions! Regarding Linux: I am already 99% of my time on my Linux OS, and only go to Windows (dual boot) to play, which happens maybe 5 times a year.